# Add binding specific CSP frame-ancestors HTTP header in IIS Site

Tags: iis, iframe, http-headers, content-security-policy

In IIS we have one Site with many binding inside it , let say Site1 has binding [www.siteone.com](http://www.siteone.com), [www.sitetwo.com](http://www.sitetwo.com). Now I have to add CSP -frame-ancestors for one binding only i.e add CSP header for  "www.siteone.com"  only,  not for "www.sitetwo.com" .

if we add below lines in web.config then these setting will apply for all the binding. Do we have any condtional way that we can use to apply that  CSP -frame-ancestors work for [www.siteone.com](http://www.siteone.com) only

```
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <clear />
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self' http://www.ancestorssite.com https://www.ancestorssite.com" />     
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

I have tried the below IIS rewrite rule but its not showing

```
<rule name="whitelist-site- iframe">
  <match url="(.*)"  />
  <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*\.?www.siteone\.com$" /> 
   <add input="{HTTP_Content_Security_Policy}" pattern="frame-ancestors ^.*\.?www.ancestorssite\.com$" />
  </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.siteone.com" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Use IIS URL Rewrite rules to add headers, where conditions can be utilized to validate domain names.

Comment: Lex , I have added URL rewrite rule as above but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with IIS outbound rule

1.Please enable URL rewrite module
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

2.Set Allow Variables for **REPONSE_Content-Security-Policy**.

[image]

3.Plesae apply this precondition and outbound rule.

```
   <outboundRules>
                <rule name="123" preCondition="Precondition1">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content-Security-Policy" pattern="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="frame-ancestors 'self' http://www.ancestorssite.com https://www.ancestorssite.com" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="Precondition1">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.siteone.com" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
```